# struct template in template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a problem with templates arguments. Here's the problem

```
template <typename T>
struct My_struct
{
    void func(T* ptr)
    { 
        /* Do stuff */ 
    }
};

template <typename T, auto U = My_struct> // Here's the problem, i'd like to give the typename T to My_struct like My_struct<T>
struct Other_struct
{
    // Do stuff
};
```

How can I do that ? Is that even possible in C++ ?

Comment: Why not just `typename U = My_struct<T>`?

Comment: `template <typename T, typename U = My_struct<T>> ...` should work. Why use `auto`?

Comment: because I'm coding a wrapper for unique_ptr for custom allocators and I need to pass the allocator via the template because that's how the custom deleters are passed to the unique_ptr

Comment: Forget it, I've found a better, cleaner solution. Thanks for your help though :D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T>
struct My_struct
{
    void func(T* ptr)
    { 
        /* Do stuff */ 
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U = My_struct<T>> 
struct Other_struct
{
    // Do stuff
};
```

You don't need auto here, use `template`

Comment: I need auto because I'm coding a wrapper for unique_ptr for custom allocators and I need to pass the allocator via the template because that's how the custom deleters are passed to the unique_ptr

Comment: Forget it, I've found a better, cleaner solution. Thanks for your help though :D